# Does django migration's AlterField cause issue if the constraint already exists in database?

Tags: postgresql, django-models, primary-key, django-migrations, django-1.11

I'm working on **Django 1.11**, **Python 2.7** and **Postgres 10.7**.

We have different environments **dev** and **prod**. And in one lower environment **dev**, the **id** column for a **Model** is not primary key. In the upper environment **prod**, it is made **PrimaryKey**.

I'm not sure how they created a table without a **PrimaryKey** column earlier in **DJango**.

I created a migration file with respect to lover environment **dev** which will be moved and deployed in **prod** environment later.
And the migration file contains required operations to alter the **id** column to PrimaryKey in the **Model** in **dev** database.

I'm confused whether it's going to create an issue in future when applying migrations in **prod** as the constraint of having **id** column as PrimaryKey already exists in **prod** environment or is it just going to ignore the operation as it's already in place.

Should I just apply the migration in lower environment and remove the operation from migration file so that it won't be applied in **prod**.

Can someone please clarify the query.